# How do you add a newline separator between grep contents from the same file?

Tags: cmd, grep

I have an output file where I can grep several patterns per model.

For example in the output file I have several Models, omega values, dates, etc.

So far I use (in cmd):

```
grep -E "Model|omega|p|date1|type" outputfile.txt
```

Results are: #some models don't have omega or p values which is fine based on the model, I still get all the important details I need

```
Model 1: First-Estimate
omega: 5
date1: 05/04/2000
type: 1.000 2.000 3.000
Model 2: Second-Estimate  
date1: 05/04/2000
type: 1.000 1.500 2.000
Model 3: Third-Estimate
omega: 5  6.1   7.5
p: 0.523  0.321  0.663
date1: 05/04/2000
Model 4: Fourth-Estimate   Field Check
omega: 1  6.2   7.6
p: 5.221  6.5312  6.222
date1: 05/04/2000
```

I am wondering, how do I insert the --group-separator function so that I can create a newline space between each instance of "Model" so that I can quickly distinguish each model group?

So I would want the output to look cleaner and more readable like:

```
Model 1: First-Estimate
omega: 5
date1: 05/04/2000
type: 1.000 2.000 3.000

Model 2: Second-Estimate  
date1: 05/04/2000
type: 1.000 1.500 2.000

Model 3: Third-Estimate
omega: 5  6.1   7.5
p: 0.523  0.321  0.663
date1: 05/04/2000

Model 4: Fourth-Estimate   Field Check
omega: 1  6.2   7.6
p: 5.221  6.5312  6.222
date1: 05/04/2000
```

It doesn't even need to be a newline separator. I tried --group-separator="====" "Model" out.txt, but nothing would show up or I ended up getting out.txt appended to the beginning of every line. Not sure of the proper syntax for this.

Comment: What version of grep are you using? Mine (GNU grep 3.1) has no option `--group-separator`.

Comment: If you post sample input we can help you. The answer you've currently accepted is certainly not the best approach.

Comment: I did post sample input. What I posted was literally what I typed in cmd and the output is exactly what I did get from an output text file. I just wanted spaces in between each instance of Model so I could read it clearly. I would love to hear other methods that utilize grep. Also for the earlier comment, I didn't have the group separator option. I thought I would because I saw other posts about it, but any use of that method gives me nothing. I don't even have awk working on my cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe output to sed and insert a newline in front of Model?

```
grep -E "Model|omega|p|date1|type" outputfile.txt|sed "s/^Model/\n&/"
```

Comment: Ah thank you. That worked! I only just learned grep commands and was unfamiliar with sed.

Comment: Actually, although this works nicely when seeing the results in the cmd line, when I save them to an output file (text format), the entire thing changes. Whereas before the sed command, I could save the results into a text file and it would look exactly as was displayed in the cmd prompt. How do I keep the format as is when writing it to an output file? Let me add that this happens when I execute the whole command from a bash script.

Comment: I can't follow, just tested it with same result in windows and bash (WSL). To save to a file just append a redirection like `>new.txt`

Comment: Yes I did, but when I open that text file everything is written in 2 lines only. It is no longer in the output (as shown above). I wrote:

Comment: grep -E "Model|omega|p|date1|type" outputfile.txt | sed "s/^Model/\n&/" > output_testfile.txt

Comment: The output has all my information in two lines with a space between them. very messy to read. But in the console, it is very clean and readable as I had wanted. I don't understand why this is. I open it with notepad, but on a different computer I opened it with NotePad++ and the format was saved. However, my work computers only use Notepad so I was wondering why the format is wonky. Maybe I need to append some extra newlines after each grep pattern is met?

Comment: I didn't have this issue neither in bash with nano nor in a windows editor. You might try with this `sed "s/^Model/\r\n&/"`

Comment: Ah that worked! It opens with proper formatting in Notepad with the \r added. Thank you! What exactly does the \r do? Is it adding those extra newlines after each pattern was met?

Comment: So this is weird - it was working when I execute it in the command prompt but I decided to save the whole command to a bash script so I can execute it quickly without having to copy/paste the whole command. Again, the output file loses its formatting when I execute my bash script (has the exact same command in it and the first line is #!/usr/bin/bash). I even used chmod -x myscript.sh to make it executable.

Comment: Depending on your exact environment several automatic conversions can occur cutting/pasting from browser to clibboard to the shell/cmd window. When in doubt use a hex viewer/editor to see whats in the file.

Comment: @DNAngel are you by any chance doing `var=$(grep ...); echo $var` in your shell script?